# Quadratic formula / stationary points

Tags: quadratic-forms

For the question find and classify the stationary points of f(x)

Given the function f(x) = ln(x^2 - 2x + 2)

Are my calculations right in thinking x = 3.75, -0.75 ?

Cheers

Comment: No.  Please try showing some of your work, and we can try to point out where things went wrong.

Comment: ok give me a second :P

Comment: http://vvcap.net/db/dsTg5hOoBZ_KsXJN0H3P.htp

Comment: You haven't even taken a derivative; how can you claim that you've found the stationary points?

Comment: Sorry, i'm pretty bad at maths... In the previous section of the question I found the derivative but I didn't think I needed it in order do this..

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of that function is:

$$f'(x) = {-2 + x\over 2-2x+x^2}$$

Set it to zero and solve for x.

**Edit** Correct derivative:

$$f'(x) = {-2 + 2x\over 2-2x+x^2}$$

Comment: well in that case x would equal 1 but surely it's not that easy ?

Comment: Definitely not 1.  You have to make the numerator zero so it would be 2.

Comment: oh god that was me being an idiot and not reading it properly -.-

Comment: Actually, it IS at $x=1$; you have an error in your derivative.

Comment: nope my derivative is the same as yours but the aim is to find the stationary points like max min ect, but I don't know how to do that from this ;o

Comment: He's right I forgot a 2, My apologies.

Comment: Damn what the hell i got 2x-2 and I've checked http://www.derivative-calculator.net/# and it says mine is correct -.-

Comment: The mins and maxes are where the derivative goes to zero.  They are where you can draw a horizontal secant line through the function. The slope is zero for horizontal lines because there is no change.

Comment: why is my derivative incorrect though ? im unsure now because the site i use says its - rather than + ...

Comment: You will need to post how you got your derivative before I can tell you that.  the derivative of what is inside the natural log is what determines where it goes to zero for this function (chain rule) and in this case the derivative of $x^2 - 2x +2$ is simply $2x - 2$ which goes to zero when $x = 2$.